# ANTLR 4 fails to indentify the '..' token in favor of two '.'

Tags: c#, antlr4

When feeding this input (fragment):

```
X,Y : ARRAY [0..3] OF CARDINAL;
```

by applying this ANTLR 4 grammar (it is a part of this [m2pim4.g4 file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/modula2pim4/m2pim4.g4) representing a Modula-2 grammar):

```
subrangeType
   : '[' constExpression '..' constExpression ']'
   ;
```

I am getting this antlr parser error:

> mismatched input '.' expecting '..'

Obviously the lexer fails to identify the `..` as token and instead yields the tokens

```
[
0.
.
3
]
```

Can I improve the grammar, or do I have to customize the lexer somehow?

I am using the NuGet package Antlr4 (4.6.6) as the C# target of the ANTLR 4 parser generator in a .NET 5.0 class library.

Comment: That's because the grammar is wrong. The lexer, which operates more or less independently from the parser, recognizes "0." as a token because when offered the choice of "0" vs "0.", Antlr will choose the longer of the two. It should not in this case. It requires a semantic predicate in the lexer rule REAL. Please create an issue in [grammars-v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) so we can fix and track this.

Comment: The rule should be `REAL : DIGIT + '.' { _input.La(1) != '.' }? DIGIT* SCALE_FACTOR? ;` for Antlr4cs, or `REAL : DIGIT + '.' { InputStream.LA(1) != '.' }? DIGIT* SCALE_FACTOR? ;` for Antlr4.

Comment: The semantic predicate predicate for Antlr4cs fixes my issue. Can you post this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry, I do not post "answers", I only post "comments". People downvote an answer if it's not perfect--like everyone is always perfect, all-knowing, their code is fantastic, and my code complete garbage. The problem with SO and our "profession".

Comment: Your answer was perfect in this case. Anyway, thanks. (Posted the git [issue #2346](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues/2346)).

Comment: @kaby76 I would encourage you to reconsider your position on not posting answers.  I've had answers downvoted for stupid reasons, it's a pain, but minor.  On the flip side, there are many times that I see an unanswered ANTLR question, and look into it to post an answer only to find that you've really provided the solution.  I don't feel good about just restating your comment as an "answer", but it's a bit of a dis-service for these "unanswered" questions to actually have an answer in the comments.  (If I notice spurious downvotes, I'll upvote to counter)

Comment: @kaby76 on the plus side, you've finally answered my nagging question: "why does Kaby always post his answers in the form of a comment?"  :)